# PHP Payment Library

Tags: php, payment-gateway, payment

Is there a simple PHP payment library that can handle multiple payment gateways? I don't mind processing the payment at the payment gateway website rather than on my site and don't want to store CC information in my site, but I want the flexibility choosing the gateway without changing the code (or little change).

Comment: Can you elaborate as to what payment gateways you're specifically looking at? Just out of interest :-)

Comment: Anything that works with major payment gateways such us Paypal, Authorize.net, Google Checkout and others

Answer (score 10):

I'd think I have to mention [payum](https://github.com/Payum/Payum). That may look a bit complicated at a first glance but give it a try!

It has well thought design, solves many common payment related issues (storing and securing data, notifications, framework agnostic). Also it [supports many payments](https://github.com/Payum/Payum/blob/master/docs/supported-gateways.md) out of the box (each shipped with a doc) and provide integration with [all favorite frameworks](https://github.com/Payum/Payum/blob/master/docs/frameworks-and-e-commerce-integration.md).

Answer (score 7):

You probably looking a library similar to Active Merchant for ruby.

There is a php port at [github](http://github.com/akDeveloper/Aktive-Merchant)

Answer (score 7):

This question might be old, but is still very relevant, and now, in 2013, the clear answer is:

**OMNIPAY**, #1 on GitHub: https://github.com/adrianmacneil/omnipay

Omnipay is professionally unit tested, available via composer and has an excellent structure. Easy to use, clean and highly professional. Offers payment gateways for

```
2Checkout
Authorize.Net AIM
Authorize.Net SIM
Buckaroo
CardSave
Dummy
eWAY Rapid 3.0
GoCardless
Manual
Migs 2-Party
Migs 3-Party
Mollie
Netaxept (BBS)
Netbanx
PayFast
Payflow Pro
PaymentExpress (DPS) PxPay
PaymentExpress (DPS) PxPost
PayPal Express Checkout
PayPal Payments Pro
Pin Payments
Sage Pay Direct
Sage Pay Server
SecurePay Direct Post
Stripe
WorldPay
```

Answer (score 2):

Upon quick googling, http://www.phpfour.com/blog/2009/02/php-payment-gateway-library-for-paypal-authorizenet-and-2checkout/ looks like it might work.

Answer (score 2):

**Kohana Payment Module** supports all the following gateways:

- Authorize.net
- Google Checkout
- Moneybookers
- Trident Gateway
- TrustCommerce
- YourPay.net
- PayPal/Paypal Pro

Comment: +1, Using Kohana. But didn't know it has all these

Answer (score 0):

I think what your looking for is an API for Paypal and similar sites.

Comment: a PHP library that integrates the APIs