# What is a good PHP Payment library that works with Paypal, Google Checkout and Authorize.net?

Tags: php, paypal, payment-gateway

What is a good PHP payment library that works with Paypal, Google Checkout and Authorize.net?

I did find this [library](http://www.phpfour.com/blog/2009/02/php-payment-gateway-library-for-paypal-authorizenet-and-2checkout/) but it is not maintained and doesn't offer Google Checkout. Is there other options such as a service that can handle those three or more gateways?

Comment: That library is only a year old and doesn't look like it is not being maintained. Why not add Google Checkout support to it yourself? Or hire someone to do it for you?

Comment: I am asking if there is such library out-there that I don't know about. If there is, then I don't need to worry about implementing it.

Answer (score 2):

Not only do they work different ways, each of these actually presents to the paying user in different ways. That means you can't really abstract them from the user, which means you really have to interface with each of them directly. There's no clean way to get around that.

The nearest alternative, then, is to find a wrapper (or set of wrappers) that allows you to *internally manage* them all similarly, so that you're not duplicating your efforts for each individual processor. I haven't found a dedicated library for this, but I've found a few options that are delivered with other frameworks. Magento has been mentioned; also Kohana, OpenCart, and even Zend Framework offer worthy and relatively modular solutions.

There are a few half-decent solutions mentioned here:
[PHP Payment Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993814/php-payment-library)

...specifically, this one has been referred/linked to a lot:
http://www.stumbleupon.com/su/2sX5Ei/www.phpfour.com/blog/2009/02/php-payment-gateway-library-for-paypal-authorizenet-and-2checkout/

I did find this -- it purports to be a commercial solution to the problem, in case you're into that sort of thing -- but I doubt it really accomplishes quite what you're looking for:
http://www.transaxdevelopers.com/PHP-Payment-Processing/PHP-Payment-Integration.asp

Another:
http://www.flexsin.com/software-web-development/payment-gateway-integration.php

Answer (score 0):

I kinda doubt that is. The fact is that Paypal, Google and Authorize.net work in different ways. Paypal handles the payment itself, and the API they expose to the developer is minimal and actually they have about 4 flavours of it (express, uk, payflow edition.. ). Google checkout as well is doing a lot of stuff in the background as integrates the checkout process itself. Authorize.net is just a payment gateway and passes more responsibility to the developer. They have a full and complex API and works only for US.

A suggestion. Take a look at [Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/) shopping cart as they implement paypal, google checkout and authorize.net modules in the default installation.

Comment: I don't know about Magento... Sure it has these, but given their tight integration with Magento, he'll need weeks just to figure them out.

Comment: this is true. I would probably study and implement each one separately in my project if this would be the case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are pure PHP systems out there. For example, there is [Virtuemart](http://virtuemart.net/) that runs on the Joomla CMS platform, which supports a wide variety of payment gateways.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to mention about my payment lib [payum](http://payum.org/) here.

Currently it supports:

- paypal express\pro checkout
- be2bill
- authorize.net AIM.

For paypal express checkout it supports [recurring payment](http://payum.org/doc/0.9/PaypalExpressCheckoutNvp/recurring-payments-basics) and digital goods features(see the doc).

The main principles(from doc):

- High level of flexibility.
- Domain models friendly payment solution.
- When you need a really good status managing.
- Storage integration (doctrin2 supported).

The lib has a [bundle](http://payum.org/doc#PayumBundle) for symfony2 and a [sandbox](https://github.com/Payum/PayumBundleSandbox) to easy start.

Hope you find it useful.